# Bug in UIDatePicker design

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

UIDatePicker is shifted as in the pic.

[image]

```
  let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
  datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
  birthDateEditText.inputView = datePickerView
```

Comment: Is that how it's being displayed in the middle of the scrolling? If yes, that's the expected behavior, try it in system apps like Calendar and see that it looks the same. Also, don't forget to ask your question. It will be easier for the others to help you if you explain what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding a custom font programmatically in appdelegate which cause this bug. I don't know why but when I remove the custom font the bug has gone.

Sorry for this unclear question.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug it is how UIDatePicker is displayed on the screen, I would add this as a comment but I can't.